# Get the total amount of the last 3 transaction of each customer from previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to get the total amount of the last 3 transactions of each customer from the previous month. Let's say today is 2012/1/31.

Please provide a step by step answer regarding why you use the approach you are using.

For example, here is the answer that I thought of. It might be wrong.

1. Create a cursor to iterate through the CustomerTransaction table group by CustomerName
2. Create the inner query to get the last 3 transactions of a customer for the previous month (using select top 3), insert it to a temporary table
3. Select the result within the temporary table and get the sum(Amount) and group it by the CustomerName.

So I have a CustomerTransaction table with these columns:

```
ID, CustomerName, Amount, TransactionDate
```

Here is a script if you need it. I am using it to test the result.

```
insert into Test.dbo.CustomerTransaction (CustomerName, Amount, TransactionDate)
values ('John', 100.0, '2011-12-31'),
('John', 100.0, '2011-12-30'),
('John', 100.0, '2011-12-29'),
('John', 100.0, '2011-12-28'),
('Boyd', 100.0, '2011-12-30'),
('Boyd', 200.0, '2011-12-29'),
('Boyd', 100.0, '2011-12-28'),
('Boyd', 100.0, '2011-12-27')
```

Comment: what is your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: next time you think of using cursors as part of your solution, do yourself a favor and kick yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself prefer the Cross Apply & Top combination for simplicity.

**UPDATE** - I have fixed the date range calculation.

Also - if you need the query to be deterministic, either use the `SELECT TOP N WITH TIES` method or add a primary key or some kind of 'uniquifier' to the `ORDER BY` clause of the `SELECT TOP` query.

```
DECLARE @fd AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @ld AS DATETIME;
SET @fd = (dateadd(month, datediff(month, -1, getdate()) - 2, -1) + 1);
SET @ld =  dateadd(month, datediff(month, -1, getdate()) - 1, -1);

WITH Customers AS (
    SELECT CustomerName
    FROM tempdb.dbo.CustomerTransaction
    GROUP BY CustomerName
)
SELECT C.CustomerName,
       SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM Customers AS C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (3) Amount
    FROM tempdb.dbo.CustomerTransaction AS T
    WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN @fd AND @ld
      AND T.CustomerName = C.CustomerName
    ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC
) Q
GROUP BY C.CustomerName;
```

Results:

```
CustomerName Total
------------ ---------------------------------------
Boyd         400.00
John         300.00
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is still wrong, but very close.  It still misses the last day.
The last day of the month at 12:00:00 AM is just the end of the previous day.
To include the full last day it should go until 11:59:59.999 PM

```
DECLARE @fd AS TIMEDATE;
DECLARE @ld AS TIMEDATE;

SET @fd = (dateadd(month, datediff(month, -1, getdate()) - 2, -1) + 1); 
SET @ld =  (dateadd(ms, -2, dateadd(month, datediff(month, -1, getdate()) - 1, -1) + 1));

PRINT @fd
PRINT @ld
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun one!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae6fd/20

```
with lastMonth as
  (

    select * from CustomerTransaction
    where
    TransactionDate >= DateAdd(m, -1, cast(cast(month(getdate()) as varchar) + '/1/' + cast(year(getdate()) as varchar) as date)) AND

    TransactionDate < cast(cast(month(getdate()) as varchar) + '/1/' + cast(year(getdate()) as varchar) as date)
  ) 


select
  customerName,
  sum(Amount) as total
from
 lastMonth lm
where 
  not exists (

    select 1 from lastMonth lm2 
    WHERE lm2.customerName = lm.customerName AND
      exists (
        select 1 from lastMonth lm3
        WHERE lm3.customerName = lm2.customerName AND
              exists (
                select 1 from lastMonth lm4
                WHERE lm4.customerName = lm3.customerName AND
                lm4.TransactionDate > lm3.TransactionDate
              ) AND
              lm3.TransactionDate > lm2.TransactionDate
      ) AND
      lm2.TransactionDate > lm.TransactionDate

  )
group by
  customerName
```

Step by step why I did it this way:

LastMonth as a CTE so I would not have to filter the base dataset repetitively, both for performance and readability.

The last three values is accomplished via a chain of not exists + exists.  These serve to filter out the data from the lastMonth so that only three records will be allowed to returned (done via what amounts to three joins).

Comment: Full disclosure: sqlfiddle.com is my site

Comment: If I add one more transaction to the table with the same date, it will count as one transaction. So instead of getting top 3, it will get top 4 (including the one transaction with the same transactiondate).    

`insert into CustomerTransaction (CustomerName, Amount, TransactionDate) values ('John', 100.0, '2011-12-29')`

Comment: That's true, I assumed transaction dates were basically time stamps, with no real possibility of duplicates.

Comment: @Wisp - something comes to mind, regarding your comment about the possibility of multiple transactions on the same date: if you allow that possibility, then how do you account for the case when there are say 5 transactions at the same time, and they are all the "last" transactions for the month?  Which three of those do you pick?  You could go on the order in which they were inserted (the identity column) but that is pretty lame and arbitrary.  So, although I will grant that your case will cause trouble for my query, I think your case will cause more problems for your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @d datetime = '2012-01-31'

declare @CustomerTransaction table(CustomerName varchar(10), Amount money, TransactionDate datetime) 

insert into @CustomerTransaction 
(CustomerName, Amount, TransactionDate) 
values ('John', 100.0, '2011-12-31'), 
('John', 100.0, '2011-12-30'), ('John', 100.0, '2011-12-29'), 
('John', 100.0, '2011-12-28'), ('Boyd', 100.0, '2011-12-30'), 
('Boyd', 200.0, '2011-12-29'), ('Boyd', 100.0, '2011-12-28'), 
('Boyd', 100.0, '2011-12-27') 

;with cte as
(
select CustomerName, Amount, TransactionDate, 
rn = row_number() over (partition by customername order by transactiondate desc) 
from @CustomerTransaction--replace with: from Test.dbo.CustomerTransaction 
where datediff(month, TransactionDate, @d) = 1
)
select CustomerName, Amount, TransactionDate 
from cte where rn < 4
```